# Save file path on show dialog

Tags: vb.net

I want to  save path on  text box after Directory 1: whenever I try to close the application and open again the path is not there.I want it to show every time I open the application.

[image]

```
Private Sub btnRootBrowse1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse1.Click
        RootFolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog()
        txtPath1.Text = RootFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need save your data (in this case txtPath1.Text) to Hard-Drive (File or DataBase) and reload it in the next execution.

It can be easy when you use [Application-Setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

1. In the Solution Explorer, Double-Click "My Project"
2. in left pane click "Setting"
3. in the table, Fill in the fields as needed, example for you case: Name: DirectoryLocation Type: String Scope: User Value: Empty.
4. Sample Code Using:

   ```vb
   Public Sub New()
       InitializeComponent()

       'load from the hard-disk
       txtPath1.Text = My.Settings.DirectoryLocation
   End Sub

   Private Sub btnRootBrowse1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse1.Click
       RootFolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog()
       txtPath1.Text = RootFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath

       'save to hard-disk
       My.Settings.DirectoryLocation = txtPath1.Text
       My.Settings.Save()
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: I tried your code but it did not save it when i reopened.

Comment: @smrithi Have you followed the steps 1-3 exactly?